# how to get full path of downloaded file

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, download, httpresponse

I want to find the downloaded files full path.

In my case, I am replacing some data in document and saving in client side, so, it automatically saving in the client side(normally in the Temp folder). I want to get that full path from the client side.

Code:

```
 Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myword.docx");
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible (short of some exploit) to determine this with modern web browsers, nor should you need it.

Comment: yes.. i need that path. coz i want to save that file back to ma server.

Comment: Sorry, but setting the filename is the best you can do. You could write a script to post a file and save the response to a specific location, but you can't control or inspect save locations from the server side.